# Cumulant GF cannot be a polynomial of degree >2

Tags: probability-theory

The cumulant generating function of a random variable $X$ is the natural log of the Moment Generating function.  Why can't it be a polynomial of degree $>2$?

I tried to think of the proof that $e^{-|t|^r}$ is not a characteristic function for r>2.  Here you take derivatives to show that the variance is 0.

Comment: This is a well-known theorem of Marcinkiewicz (1935). It's proved in Lukacs' book on characteristic functions, which you can probably find in the library. But I don't know the proof, haven't found it on the Web, and don't want to try it myself (it's probably quite hard).